# Internal PDF viewer of Texmaker deforms the preview pdf

Tags: texmaker, viewers

I use Texmaker 4.1.1 (and MiKTeX 2.9).
After a complete reinstallation of my computer, the internal PDF viewer of Texmaker started to deform the preview of the PDF document. Meaning the pages looked ''clinched''. The lines more narrow, the font too low and too wide... (The output PDF document looks normal.)

Does anyone have any idea why that is?

---

edit: I have added a picture to visualise what I mean

edit #2: tex source for the example below:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[]{}
\usepackage{lingmacros}
\usepackage{tree-dvips}
\begin{document}

\section*{Notes for My Paper}

Don't forget to include examples of topicalization.
They look like this:

{\small
\enumsentence{Topicalization from sentential subject:\\ 
\shortex{7}{a John$_i$ [a & kltukl & [el & 
  {\bf l-}oltoir & er & ngii$_i$ & a Mary]]}
{ & {\bf R-}clear & {\sc comp} & 
  {\bf IR}.{\sc 3s}-love   & P & him & }
{John, (it's) clear that Mary loves (him).}}
}

\subsection*{How to handle topicalization}

I'll just assume a tree structure like (\ex{1}).

{\small
\enumsentence{Structure of A$'$ Projections:\\ [2ex]
\begin{tabular}[t]{cccc}
    & \node{i}{CP}\\ [2ex]
    \node{ii}{Spec} &   &\node{iii}{C$'$}\\ [2ex]
        &\node{iv}{C} & & \node{v}{SAgrP}
\end{tabular}
\nodeconnect{i}{ii}
\nodeconnect{i}{iii}
\nodeconnect{iii}{iv}
\nodeconnect{iii}{v}
}
}

\subsection*{Mood}

Mood changes when there is a topic, as well as when
there is WH-movement.  \emph{Irrealis} is the mood when
there is a non-subject topic or WH-phrase in Comp.
\emph{Realis} is the mood when there is a subject topic
or WH-phrase.

\end{document}
```

[image: previewed document]

Comment: same with external pdf viewer ?

Comment: 1) How was compiled the document (pdflatex or latex+dvips+ps2pdf)
2) Are you sure that the pdf produced is valid?
3) Note : on the first use on windows, the poppler library (used by the pdf viewer) must have the time to scan all the fonts installed on the system.

Comment: @abhilashsukumari - no. with the external pdf viewer the output looks perfektly normal.

Comment: @user27168 - 
1) pdflatex + view pdf 
2) ... I dont really understand that question. I can open the pdf document with the acrobat reader. How do I know the pdf is ''invalid''? 
3) I dont know whether it did scan them or not. Can I trigger that scan manually? (like with one of the MiKTeX  administration tools?)

Comment: Can we have the source of the document or a minimal example?

Comment: @user27168 - of course. But it does not depend on the document. This is example code I found on the internet, to check whether my document was somehow causing that behaviour.

Comment: I have the same problem (native Linux). On my Laptop it works fine, but on my desktop it's deformed, both are running the exact same versions. According to one answer (virtualbox resolution), it may be a bug due to display resolution? My laptop (non-deformed) has 1920x1080, my desktop (deformed) has 1920x1200.

Comment: Based on answers and comments on http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186854/pdf-internal-viewer-looks-stretched-and-is-too-wide, I suspect this is a 'local issue', possibly related to drivers. Certainly not a problem we can hope to help with.

Comment: Why did you close this question? It is clearly about 'Related software'! Also, do you mean 'local issue' or 'locale issue'? (It looks like the deformed preview has about the same aspect ratio as U.S. Letter, whereas I want it to be A4). I still have the problem, and can't check out what you referenced since that has been deleted.

Comment: I had the same issue, tried alot with all the answers below to fix it, but I couldn't. Finally I decided to use TeXstudio and it works even better than texmaker and it is more user-friendly!

Answer (score 4):

I reproduced this using the following:

Windows 7 SP1 running in Virtualbox 4.3.6 (on a CentOS 6.4 host)

Texmaker 4.1.1 with MikTex 2.9.5105

The pdf's are deformed in the internal pdfviewer, but look normal in Acrobat reader.

The deformity depends on the size of the virtualbox window: a narrow virtualbox window, results in a narrow pdf in the pdfviewer, while a wide virtualbox window results in a too wide pdf in the pdfviewer. It seems the pdfviewer is using monitor aspect ratio (not resolution) and that this value is not updated when resizing the virtualbox window. I presume Extended display identification data (EDID) is used by the pdfviewer or one of its components. The monitor size and aspect ratio obtained via EDID is not always correct...

Workaround: Play with your virtualbox window width, to get the ratio approx. right.

Workaround 2 (also works for non-virtual machines): You can override your EDID information manually see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj133967(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 3):

All works fine (windows 7 + texmaker 4.1.1 + miktex 2.9) :

[image: Texmaker pdf viewer and acrobat reader]

Comment: well... I reinstalled MiKTex + TexMaker - that did not solve the problem. 

since it seems to be a ''problem'' that occurs only on my system.
I think that there is some small .dll, which poppler needs, 
missing on my system... 

but thanks for the help anyway

Comment: All the required dlls are included in the package. But there is perhap's another conflicting version of a poppler dll on the system. You should try first to reset the texmaker settings (Options -> settings file)

Comment: resetting the options didnt do the trick either

Comment: For me, resetting the options helped. Thanks!